# No replacement of question mark in prepared SQL statement

Tags: php, sql

I use PDO in PHP on a MariaDB to filter rows where text field contains `$search_terms`. However, I only retrieve the rows which contain a question mark. It seems that the content of `$search_terms` is not replaced in the prepared statement.

```
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM notes WHERE text LIKE \'%?%\'');
$query->execute(array($search_terms));
$data['notes'] = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Why ?

Comment: Won't work [that way](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#like), needs other handling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if `$search_terms` is intended to hold one or more than one search term.  Your query implies the former, and if so, then use:

```
$search_term = "%apple%";
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM notes WHERE text LIKE ?');
$query->execute($search_term);
$data['notes'] = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Note that we bind the search term with the `%` wildcards to the statement.  The statement just holds a single `?` placeholder.